# How to stop flask app.run()?

Tags: python, flask

I made a flask app following flask's tutorial. After `python flaskApp.py`, how can I stop the app? I pressed `ctrl + c` in the terminal but I can still access the app through the browser. I'm wondering how to stop the app? Thanks.

I even rebooted the vps. After the vps is restated, the app still is running!

Comment: did you hard reload the web page ? 'Ctrl + F5'

Comment: @HassanMehmood I did.

Comment: please try `ps -e | grep python*` and see if python is still running

Comment: @Harrison and how did you started your app ? python run.py ?

Comment: @Mrunmoy the command outputs nothing

Comment: @HassanMehmood Yes. `python flaskr.py`

Comment: are you using apache ?

Comment: @HassanMehmood Yes

Comment: then simple Ctrl + C will not work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111703/discussion-between-harrison-and-hassan-mehmood).

Comment: you have to delete .conf file from sites-enable folder

Comment: @Harrison I'm unable to open chat url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using apache so in order to stop your app, you have to disable it by deleting .conf file from '/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/' folder and then restart the apache server. This will surely destroy your current running session.

```
$ cd /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
$ sudo rm conf_filename.conf
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Try it and your site will be down. To enable it again, copy paste your file to '/etc/apache2/sites-available/' and run the following commands to enable it again.

```
$ sudo a2ensite conf_filename.conf
$ sudo service apache2 restart
```

Now your site will be live again.

Answer (score 2):

CTRL+C is the right way to quit the app, I do not think that you can visit the url after CTRL+C. In my environment it works well.

What is the terminal output after CTRL+C? Maybe you can add some details.

You can try to visit the url by curl to test if browser cache or anything related with browser cause this problem.

Comment: My environment -- OS: Ubuntu 14.04 Flask: 0.10.1

Comment: @Harrison Do you have any logic in the app that block the keyboard input?

Comment: I followed the tutorial http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/tutorial/#tutorial. I don't think it has something that advanced, although I have no idea of what mutithread is. `ctrl + c` worked fine before.

Comment: @Harrison In my environment, after ctrl + c the terminal is able to input again, how about yours?

Comment: @Harrison In the tutorial Flask itself works as a web server, does apache do anything in your machine?

Comment: I use mod_wsgi(apache). Before I did get a 404 error after I `ctrl+c`.

Comment: @Harrison ctrl+c is the way to stop the python script, it will not work if you use apache as the web server I think.You can update description in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `pkill python`?
**WARNING**: do not do so before consulting your system admin if are sharing a server with others.

Comment: Also checkout [this code snippet](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/67/).